# SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. In Solidity version ^0.8.7

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

*Hey Guys, I'm using latest solidity version 0.8.7. I'm getting this SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. Please help me regarding this problem. When I run **npm run test** command, it gives me this error. I really need help to get rid of this issue. That's why I'm not able to proceed further in learning solidity. **Thanks a lot***

**Lottery.sol File - **

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;     // latest solidity version...

contract Lottery 
  {
   address public manager;
   address[] public players;

 constructor() 
  { 
        manager = msg.sender;
  }

function enter() public payable
 {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
 }
function random() private view returns (uint256)
 {
   return
   uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players)));
 }

function pickWinner() public restricted 
{
    require(msg.sender == manager);
    uint256 index = random() % players.length;
    uint256 amount = address(this).balance;
    payable(players[index]).transfer(amount);
    players = new address[](0); 
}

modifier restricted() 
{
    require(msg.sender == manager);
    _;
}

function getPlayers() public view returns (address[] memory) 
{
    return players;
}
}
```

**Compile.js File -**

```
const path = require("path"); 
const fs = require("fs"); 
const solc = require("solc");
const lotteryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Lottery.sol'); 
const source = fs.readFileSync(lotteryPath, "utf8");    

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'lottery.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
};

const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));       // error on this line probably

const interface = output.contracts['lottery.sol'].lotteryPath.abi;
const bytecode = output.contracts['lottery.sol'].lotteryPath.evm.bytecode.object;

module.exports = {
    interface,
    bytecode,
};
```

**lottery.test.js File**

```
const assert = require("assert");
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { interface, bytecode } = require("../compile");

let lottery;
let accounts;

beforeEach(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  lottery = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))          // error on this line probably
    .deploy({ data: bytecode })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });
});

describe("Lottery Contract", () => {
  it("deploys a contract", () => {
    assert.ok(lottery.options.address);
  });
});
```

**deploy.js File -**

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const { interface, bytecode } = require("./compile");
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  

  "*******************************************",

  "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/********************"
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  console.log("Attempting to deploy from accoutns", accounts[0]);

  const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({ data: bytecode})
    .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });

  console.log("Contract deployed to", result.options.address);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps.

**Step 1: Check the solidity compiler version**
Go to your `package.json` file. Under the `dependencies` object you will find the `solc` version.
Here make sure the solidity version is the same that you used in your `Lottery.sol` file.
If the version is not the same then please install the right version using `npm`
In my case, I am using `^0.8.8` in my solidity file. So I run the following command:

```
npm install solc@0.8.8
```

**Step 2: Update your lottery.test.js file**
In your `lottery.test.js` file update this line

```
lottery = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
```

to this

```
lottery = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface)
```

**Step 3: Update your deploy.js file**
In your `deploy.js` file update this line

```
const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
```

to this

```
const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface)
```

Also, it's a good practice to add your deployment code into a try/catch block like this:

```
try {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log("Attempting to deploy from accoutns", accounts[0]);

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface)
        .deploy({ data: bytecode})
        .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });

    console.log("Contract deployed to", result.options.address);
 } catch(error) {
   console.log(error);
 }
```

**Note:** Finally ensure in your deployment account you have enough ethers to test with. If you don't then get some ethers using faucets